# Bing map embed code

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I want to use bing map embed code. Which I am not able to find on the bing map. I want to use this on ly website.

I am searching for this location:
Omni Mandalay Hotel at Las Colinas
221 East Las Colinas Ave
Irving, Texas 75039

Can I please get any help on this.

I only want to use bing map no google map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you find the location you want, there is a share button in the top right corner.  Once you click that an overlay appears and you will find the embed code.  The embed code for the location you referenced would be this:

```
<div id="mapviewer"><iframe id="map" scrolling="no" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src="https://www.bing.com/maps/embed/?v=2&amp;cp=32.876173~-96.941603&amp;lvl=15&amp;sty=r&amp;where1=Irving%2C%20Texas%2C%2075039&amp;ss=yp.Omni%20Mandalay%20Hotel%20at%20Las%20Colinas~pg.1~rad.80&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;emid=0d672ee5-c816-0a5a-45b8-47e9af4c2e70"></iframe><div id="LME_maplinks" style="line-height:20px;"><a id="LME_largerMap" href="https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=32.876173~-96.941603&amp;lvl=15&amp;sty=r&amp;where1=Irving%2C%20Texas%2C%2075039&amp;ss=yp.Omni%20Mandalay%20Hotel%20at%20Las%20Colinas~pg.1~rad.80&amp;form=LMLTEW" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">View Larger Map</a><a id="LME_directions" href="https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=32.876173~-96.941603&amp;lvl=15&amp;sty=r&amp;where1=Irving%2C%20Texas%2C%2075039&amp;ss=yp.Omni%20Mandalay%20Hotel%20at%20Las%20Colinas~pg.1~rad.80&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;rtp=%7Epos.32.87617255002736_-96.94160270019577_North%20Irving" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">Driving Directions</a></div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: After getting my location i click on the hotel and clicked on share button on the right top side. and it gives me overlay but i only get this "Show full URL" and if I am putting this in iframe its not working. The code with you have provided me I am not getting it.

Comment: I added an image that should clarify all the options of how to get the embed code and customize its display.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find documentation on how to create a custom URL for the Bing Maps site here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx